# iOS:Cordova InAppBrowser app is running on the iPad and the soft keyboard can't be ejected by focus () under certain conditions

Tags: ios, cordova, focus, android-softkeyboard, inappbrowser

We using the Angular5.2.9 + Ionic3.2 + Ionic Native 4.5.3 + Cordova8.0 to make an app with a Cordova InAppBrowser, and access the following HTML in the app:

[testsoftkeyboard3.html:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n89gP.png)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var objInput1=null;
    var objInput2=null;

    function initLoad()
    {
        objInput1=document.getElementById("input1");
        objInput2=document.getElementById("input2");
    }

    function onBlur(event)
    {
        if(event.target.value == 'abc')
        {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
            return true;
        }

            //If we do not use setTimeout to perform alert here,
            //the InAppBrowser will die without responding to any action in the Pattern2
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('Please input abc');
                //objInput1.focus();
                //objInput1.click();
            }, 0);

        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        event.target.focus();
        event.target.click();

        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(document.activeElement.id);
            //objInput1.focus();
            //objInput1.click();
        }, 2000);

        return false;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:initLoad()">
input1:<input type="text" id="input1" onblur="javascript:onBlur(event);"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp - &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
input2:<input type="text" id="input2"/>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is designed to achieve the following effects:

Step1. When the focus in the input1, the ipad automatically display soft keyboard (It's should be iOS default function, focus on the input box will automatically eject the soft keyboard)

[The ScreenShot of Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC96b.png)

Step2. When we enter content in input1, it will show alert warning if it found that the input is not "abc" when the input1 lose focus (implemented in the onblur event)

[The ScreenShot of Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEuSi.png)

Step3. At the same time , the background color of the input1 will be changed to red, and let the focus return to the input1 and automatically display the soft keyboard again

[The ScreenShot of Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHqNb.png)

Our problem is, at the Step2, we can make input1 lose focus in two ways(The Pattern1 and The Pattern2):

Pattern1. Use mouse to click input2

Pattern2. Press the button in the lower right corner of the soft keyboard to put the keyboard away 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY1AN.png)

At present, when we operate by Pattern1, there is no problem, the Step3 can be expected to show the effect.

But when we operate by Pattern2, when by calling the focus() method to make input1 get the focus, soft keyboard will flash (appear, and immediately disappear), tried a lot of ways to keep the soft keyboard always appear, we already took 2, 3 days to try to solve the problem, are not done.

Do not know whether need to modify InAppBrowser's Objective-C code? 
Is there any way to control the soft keyboard show or hide by code?

Please help us. Thank you very much.

Comment: Environment:Angular v5.2.9
Ionic v3.2
Ionic Native v4.5.3
Ionic Angular v3.9.2
Cordova v8.0.0
Cordova-ios v4.5.4
Cordova-plugin-inappbrowser v2.0.3-dev
macOS High Sierra v10.13.3
Xcode v9.3(9E145)
npm v5.6.0
Node.js v8.11.1

Comment: PS: We used cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard ver 2.0.5